# how to generate n random integers of k digits

Tags: python

Is there a way to create n random integers of k digits.

For example.. 2000 random integers comprising of `[0, 2, 3]`

My trick was to use a random number of generator and then assign values based on the the ranges?

But was wondering if there is a better way to do this in python?

Edit: 
Example: [0,0,0, 2, 2,3,0,0,2,2,..... 2000 elements] comprising of 0,2 and 3
my approach

```
    def assign(x):
        if x< 0.3: return 0
        elif x<0.6: return 2
        else: return 3

    x = np.random.rand(num)

    x = map(lamdba x:assign(x),x)
```

Comment: This needs some statistical-model first. Or is the number consisting of 10^7 digits equally probable compared to the number 2?

Comment: Please, improve your question: 1. Add desired output; 2. Describe what you have tried so far (in code). It's very strange to see such a poor question from a gold-badger.

Comment: Can you give an example? Are you looking to generate `n` integers, each of which being either `2`, `3`, or `0` with equal weight?

Comment: So, do you want 2000 random ints with k digits comprising 0, 2, and 3? So if k=3, then e.g. 230, 222, 323, etc.? Or are 0, 2, and 3 the "k" allowed digits, and the total number of digits in the integer is arbitrary? Are duplicates allowed?

Comment: I believe that he wants to generate a random sequence using only the integers found in the list k. In which case simple list comprehension + random.choice is the best option imo.

Comment: @Billylegota Numpy's random.choice would be even better (size-param; sample-strategy-param), but i have doubts about your interpretation.

Comment: @sascha It was unclear as to whether or not numpy was available. I try to use pure python code unless told explicitly that libraries such as numpy are available.

Comment: @Billylegota I don't dislike your approach, just the statement about it's power. Now, that he probably wants to use probabilities (discrete-sampling), numpy's approach is much more interesting. But you are right: it's not always available!

Comment: In `assign()` _3_ has prob 0.4 vs 0.3 for 1 and 2. Is this bias towards returning 3 deliberate? If so the currently accepted answer is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the sounds of it, it looks like you want to generate a sequence of length `n` using only the values found within the list `k`.

Python's `random.choice` function combined with list comprehension is perfect for this.

The following function will generate a list of length n with each element being a random element chosen from `k`.

```
from random import choice

def random_choices(n, k):
    return [choice(k) for _ in xrange(n)]
```

Here is the same thing as simple list comprehension.

```
from random import choice
foo = [choice(k) for _ in xrange(n)]
```

*Thanks to Mr.goosberry for pointing out that `xrange` should be replaced with `range` in python 3.x.x.

Comment: It's not clear that this is what OP wants, and without any explanation this isn't a great answer even if it is.

Comment: @AdamSmith sorry, I was just excited to find a question I could answer and wanted to write out my answer before someone else did ;D

Comment: Fastest gun in the west is a real thing, but fight that urge ;-)

Comment: You might want to ask if he is using python2 or python3 to put the right range function in your answer, but thats just my little qualm. And by the way, nice answer ;).

Comment: OP is constructing some non-uniform sampling example and accepts a solution doing uniform-sampling. Sometimes SO is just madness. But despite of the py2/py3 troubles, this answer is good (in the uniform-model).

Answer (score 1):

Now after your edit, it is clear what you want. You want discrete-sampling of some elements within a container.

Just prepare your classes and do this:

```
import numpy as np
classes = [0, 2, 3]
samples = np.random.choice(classes, 2000)
```

If you want some specific probabilities:

```
import numpy as np
classes = [0, 2, 3]
samples = np.random.choice(classes, 2000, p=[0.3, 0.3, 0.4])
```

See the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html).

The implementation should be much faster than your approach which is sometimes called roulette-wheel-sampling or linear-search-sampling. There are some possible algorithms mentioned at [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-random_number_sampling).

Answer (score 1):

You may achieve it via `list comprehension`. In order to show the result I am using `20`. Change it to `2000` as per your requirement.

```
>>> import random
>>> x = 20
>>> [random.choice([0, 2, 3]) for i in range(20)]
[2, 2, 3, 2, 0, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 0, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2]
```

Comment: @AdamSmith how so? Just curious.

Comment: @AdamSmith got you.

Answer (score 1):

You're willing to use numpy, so I'd recommend you use [np.random.choice](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html), ie:

```
import numpy as np

N = 2000
print[np.random.choice([0, 2, 3], p=[1/3.0, 1/3.0, 1/3.0]) for x in range(N)]
```

Comment: Nice redundancy :-)

Comment: @sascha Lol, we posted at the same time, haven't found a way to give 1/3 probability to the 3 values... they won't sum 1

Comment: What are you doing... If you want uniform-sampling, then don't set p (=None)! (And if you are crazy: use ```p=[1/3.0, 1/3.0, 1/3.0]```).

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
N = 10
# Generate three vectors of n size
zeros = np.zeros((N,), dtype = np.int) 
twos = np.zeros((N,), dtype = np.int) + 2
threes = np.zeros((N,), dtype = np.int) + 3
# Permutate all together
df = []
df = np.append(df, [zeros, twos, threes])
df_shuffled = np.random.shuffle(df)
print(df)
```